# jQuery .trigger() or $(window) not working in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash

I have this jQuery ajax navigation tabs plugin that I created using some help from CSS-Tricks.com and the [jQuery hashchange event](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/) plugin (detects hash changes in browsers that don't support it).

The code is little long to post it here but it goes something like this:

Part 1) When a tab is clicked, it gets the href attribute of that tab and add it to the browsers navigation bar like '#tab_name': `window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");`

Part 2) When the navigation bar changes (hash change), it gets the href change like this: `window.location.hash.substring(1);` (substring is to get only 'tab_name' without the '#'), and then call the ajax function to get the info to display.

I want to automatically trigger the plugin to load the first tab when the page is accessed, so at the start of the code I put:

```
if (window.location.hash === '') { // If no '#' is in the browser navigation bar
   window.location.hash = '#tab_1'; // Add #tab_1 to the navigation bar
   $(window).trigger('hashchange'); // Trigger a hashchange so 'Part 2' of the plugin calls the ajax function using the '#tab_1' added
}
```

The probles is that it works in FF but not in Chrome, I mean, everything works but it seems like the `$(window).trigger('hashchange');` is not working because it doesnt get the first tab..

Any suggestions??

Note: It worked some time ago but suddenly it doesn't (maybe Chrome update).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you're attempting to trigger the event in a way the browser is not happy with. Where is your handler for "hashchange" defined?  I suggest you try binding it to

```
$('body').bind('hashchange', function() { ... })
```

instead of "window".  Even that might give you problems in WebKit browsers; if so, you can create a `<div>` to wrap your body content, and bind to that.

Comment: Well, the hashchange is defined like this: $(window).bind('hashchange', function() { ...

Comment: I found the problem, I wass calling $(window).trigger('hashchange'); before the hashcnage was defined in $(window).bind('hashchange', function() { ... Thanks por pointing me to the direction!